# Image shrinks on scroll down, JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need a `JQuery` code which lets me do following.

As I **scroll down**, the `image` in the header will start to shrink and once I have scrolled enough(such that **focus** has now been shifted to content rather than the header), the image in the header should dock to top in a small size.

It is much like the techcrunch.com scenario, but i am unable to replicate that.

Comment: can you show the code what you have done so far?

Comment: Haven't done anything yet, need a code which can accomplish this

Comment: This isn't the purpose of stackoverflow.

Comment: oh! i'll try and write some code then and come back

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I suggest using a plugin like [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/),
with the shortcut ["sticky elements"](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/), which makes docking an element after it loses focus an easy task :)

---

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FXSaP/) | Code

```js
$('.my-sticky-element').waypoint('sticky');
```